# Problems with using SWCs containing symbols with overlapping names

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, swc

I am creating an AS3 project which contains various SWCs given to me by a third-party. These SWCs come from 2 different FLAs, but some of the exported symbols in these FLAs have the same structure/symbol names.

When I use both of these SWCs, the symbols inside lose their actionscript (for example, Flash ignores stop()). If I remove one of this SWCs from the library path, the assets from the other SWC works 100% fine.

I need to use both these SWCs. Anyone can offer a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you cannot rebuild at least one of the swc files and rename things things in its library, then the only other thing I can think of is when you reference them do with with their full namespace instead of just their class name. This is a common solution used in other OOP languages as well.

For eaxmple, you have 2 classes/library items and they are both named "Pizza." If for one you use `import com.eastcoast.*` and the other you use `import com.westcoast.*` then instead of just saying something like

`var pepperoiniPizza:Pizza = new Pizza();`

You would say

`var pepperoiniPizza:com.eastcoast.Pizza = new com.eastcoast.Pizza();`

Let me know if that works.

Comment: These classes are generated by Flash and not by me. They are default package. The symbols' exports are also different, but something else is going on.

For example, if I export one SWC from Flash, then its assets work fine and the assets of the other one doesn't. Once I export the other SWC, they flip - the one last exported works fine. By "not working fine" I only mean that some of the code inside MovieClips is ignored. The assets themselves appear alright.

Comment: Ha! I fixed it. Changing the FLA names and then recompiling the SWCs did the trick. Weird.